# App is crashing after an IAP - only after podfiles were updated

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have an IAP setup in an app, along with a few Cocoapods:

```
  - Firebase/AdMob (4.8.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 7.27.0)
  - Firebase/Core (4.8.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.5)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.13)
  - Firebase/Crash (4.8.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseCrash (= 2.0.2)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.5):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.13):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseCrash (2.0.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
```

IAP and all of the above frameworks are working perfect! No problems at all.

**Once I do a pod update, things start to go south.**

After a pod update, here are the updated versions:

PODS:

```
  - Firebase/AdMob (4.10.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 7.29.0)
  - Firebase/Core (4.10.1):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.17)
  - Firebase/Crash (4.10.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseCrash (= 2.0.2)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.17):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseCrash (2.0.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
```

After this pod update - my IAP crashes on a successful purchase 100% of the time. Absolutely nothing changed in code. Just a pod update to the newest frameworks listed above.

I am getting the following crash once the IAP completes (and the "You're all set!" success alert pops up):

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) 

    libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x1859bc2e0 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x148
    0x1859bc2e4 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1859bc2e8 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1859bc300               ; <+32>
    0x1859bc2ec <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1859bc2f0 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1859bc2f4 <+20>: bl     0x18599cbdc               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1859bc2f8 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1859bc2fc <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1859bc300 <+32>: ret
```

Here is a screenshot of the debug panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exmsO.png

```
[![Debug panel][1]][1]
```

Here is what Firebase crash reporting is logging:

```
-[__NSCFBoolean timeIntervalSince1970]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b6f8a878
```

***Some items to note:***

- Nothing at all changed in code.
- Cocoapods were updated in terminal. Steps: 1. CD to dir, 2. $ pod update
- I tested the IAP before updating Cocoapods - everything worked flawless; the app did not crash.
- I did a project clean before testing the IAP after Cocoapod update.
- Crashing on multiple devices - (iOS 11.2.6  and 11.2.1).

**What is causing this crash since I only updated pods?**

**Bounty update:**

I have added a Bounty to this question because I am now experiencing it on other projects. I had an old project that i wanted to update the Pods (Firebase / Firebase Crash / Google Ads). Here are the exact steps I took:

1. CD to project directory.
2. Pod update. Cocoapods did not give me any errors at all.

Within Xcode, I run the project whose Podfile I updated... I go through purchasing an IAP and it crashes as soon as it's complete. Again, this does not happen before the pod file was updated! The IAP works fine until I run pod update.

With the newly offended broken project, I removed Podfile, Podfile.lock, and Pods directory. I dragged the same files and directory in from an older project. Works perfect without any crashing.

This problem is persisting ONLY after pod update. I'm lost..

IAP Helper file

```
  import StoreKit
import Firebase

public typealias MYProductIdentifier = String
public typealias MYProductRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()

// MARK: - Class

public class IAPHelper: NSObject {

    // Define properties!
    fileprivate let myProductIdentifiers: Set<MYProductIdentifier>
    fileprivate var myPurchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<MYProductIdentifier>()

    // Optional properties
    fileprivate var myProductsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    fileprivate var myProductsRequestCompletionHandler: MYProductRequestCompletionHandler?


    // NOTIFICATION
    static let IAPTransactionInProgress = "IAPTransactionInProgress"
    static let IAPTransactionFailed = "IAPTransactionFailed"
    static let myIAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification" // Whenever a purchase takes place!
    static let myRestorePurchaseNotification = "myRestorePurchaseNotification" // Whenever a restore takes place!
    static let myPurchaseMadeThankYou = "myPurchaseMadeThankYou" // Whenever a first purchase takes place!


    // init!
    public init(productIDs: Set<MYProductIdentifier>) {
        myProductIdentifiers = productIDs

        // CHECK IF USER ALREADY BOUGHT! (to set the correct Defaults)
        for productIdentifier in productIDs {
            let purchased = MYConstants.nsDefaults.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
            if purchased {
                myPurchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
                print("Already purchased! \(productIdentifier)")
            }
            else {
                print("Not yet purchased! \(productIdentifier)")
            }
        }

        super.init()

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    }


    public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping MYProductRequestCompletionHandler) {
        myProductsRequest?.cancel()
        myProductsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

        myProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: myProductIdentifiers)
        myProductsRequest?.delegate = self
        myProductsRequest?.start()
    }

    public func buyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    public func isProductPurchased(productIdentifier: MYProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return myPurchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
    }

    public class func canMakePayment() -> Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    }

    public func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

}

// MARK: - SKProductRequestsDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let products = response.products
        myProductsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
        reset()
    }

    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Called wheneever there is an ERROR or NO PRODUCTS!
        myProductsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
        reset()
        print("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    private func reset() {
        myProductsRequest = nil
        myProductsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
    }

}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    // Tells us if the payment from the user was successful. Then react accordingly!

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        // Check outstanding transactions and react to them.
        for transaction in transactions {
            // check what kind of transaction is happening!
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased :
                completeTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            case .failed :
                failedTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            case .restored :
                restoreTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            case .deferred :
                showTransactionAsInProgress(deferred: true)
            case .purchasing :
                showTransactionAsInProgress(deferred: false)
            }
        }

    }

    //MARK: Payment transaction related methods
    private func showTransactionAsInProgress(deferred: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(IAPHelper.IAPTransactionInProgress), object: deferred)
    }


    private func completeTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        postPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(IAPHelper.myPurchaseMadeThankYou), object: nil)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func failedTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        // User aborts payment!!
        if transaction.error!._code != SKError.Code.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            print("Error: \(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(IAPHelper.IAPTransactionFailed), object: transaction.error)

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func restoreTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else {
            return
        }

        postRestoreNotificationForIdentifier(identifier: productIdentifier)


        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }





    private func postPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(identifier: String?) {
        // TELL VC THAT PURCHASE WAS OR WAS NOT success.
        guard let identifier = identifier else {
            return
        }

        Analytics.logEvent("IAP_Purchase_Made", parameters: nil)


        // I believe it crashes right here.

        // NEW ==================================
        myPurchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
        MYConstants.nsDefaults.set(true, forKey: identifier)
        MYConstants.unlockLogic(restoring: false)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(IAPHelper.myIAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
        // END NEW ==============================

    }



    private func postRestoreNotificationForIdentifier(identifier: String?) {
        // TELL VC THAT PURCHASE WAS OR WAS NOT success.
        guard let identifier = identifier else {
            return
        }

        Analytics.logEvent("IAP_Restore_Made", parameters: nil)

        // NEW ==================================
        myPurchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
        MYConstants.nsDefaults.set(true, forKey: identifier)
        print("NEW RESTORE Identifier: \(identifier)")
        MYConstants.unlockLogic(restoring: true)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(IAPHelper.myRestorePurchaseNotification), object: nil)
        // END NEW ==============================

    }



}
```

Comment: you may changed a firebase key (remoteConfigs) from date to bool , check that

Comment: @Sh_Khan - I have not. Once the IAP completes, a userdefault gets changed. But that configuration worked perfect before the pod update. Before the update, I tested on multiple devices with successful results each time. Crash is happening only after doing a pod update (and nothing else was changed).

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @GIJOW - I could.. however it would take some time to obfuscate personal/sensitive information. Is there a particular section that you'd want to analyze? (example - the IAPHelper file). I didn't think I would need to post any code - because everything works flawless with the original pod file versions i posted - which leads me to believe this is a cocoapods or firebase conflict.

Comment: @Joe can you please share IAP file

Comment: @MAhipal Singh Edited my question to include my IAP Helper file

Comment: @Joe please try my answer and make sure you include SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self) in your View Controller

Comment: did you update your cocoapods as well `gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: @zero3nna Yes, I updated cocoapods before running pod install (which breaks the app)

Comment: Is it also crashing if you delete the app and install it fresh (persistence problem)?

Comment: Yes, still crashes. It's a non-consumable IAP so I've just been deleting it / reinstalling it to test.

Comment: @zero3nna - see my answer I just posted. The issue is temporarily resolved, but will presumably occur again once I update pods to the latest version.

Comment: This thread is quite interesting to me, as I am experiencing the same thing. I was using version 7.42.0 of the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK pod, and I was seeing this. After reading through this and the other linked SO post, I decided to try updating to a newer version of that framework, so I updated my pod file. Previously:
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.42.0' Now:
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.42.1' I re-ran the exact same test scenario that was crashing, and now it's not crashing. Can anyone else verify this, or any I just hitting a fluke situation and getting lucky here? Am I going to continue

Comment: @PaulBrown - Are you getting the timeIntervalSince1970 crash? And what is the scenario you're running? I'm yet to resolve this, after over a year. My App is stuck with Firebase 4.8.0. I am unable to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this crash occurs when `registerDefaults:` is used to register a user preference key that is the same as the IAP product identifier.

This exception always occurs when the NSUserDefaults key that is the same as the IAP product ID key is has a default prefs value registered like so:

```
#define kTipPurchasedIAPProductIdKey @"tipAdditional99Cents"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.


  if (YES) {
      //Firebase initialization
      [FIRApp configure];
      [[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance] setLoggerLevel:FIRLoggerLevelMin];
  }

    //Register user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{
                                                              kTipPurchasedIAPProductIdKey: @NO
                                                              }];
}
```

In this case the IAP product ID key (that you would use to validate whether the iAP exists, etc) is tipAdditional99Cents. The crash occurs when the transaction returns as purchased/restored.

The current workaround is to register a different key in the user defaults instead of the actual IAP product ID.

I reported it to Google Firebase on their Github repository [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4176) and they will fix the bug in the next release (6.13.0, fixed 14NOV2019).

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing this to googles attention!

Answer (score 3):

To find where is this call for the TimeInterval being made I would add a public extension for Bool so you can add a breakpoint to it and modify accordingly.

Something like this:

```
public extension Bool {
    public var timeIntervalSince1970:TimeInterval {
        get {
            // Add breakpoint here
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I failed to recognise your crash mentiones NSCFBoolean and not Bool.
As I understand NSCFBoolean is a private class bridging CFBoolean, so you can't extend it, but maybe it works by extending CFBoolean. More on NSCFBoolean: https://nshipster.com/bool/

Please, try adding this extension and breakpoint:

```
public extension CFBoolean {
    var timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval {
        get {
            // Add breakpoint here
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nearly 1 year later, I am still having this issue. It's completely preventing me from updating Firebase Core. @vauxhall - can you please further explain your answer? I added that extension, added the breakpoint above the return statement, and nothing shows up in console. It crashes, but I see nothing to do with the timeIntervalSince1970 extension.

Comment: Hi @vauxhall - That also did not work. I added a breakpoint above the return statement, along with a print statement, and neither were recognized from the console when the crash occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I've ***temporarily*** fixed this issue by going back to the pod versions before I ran the update.

**Here are the exact steps I took:**

1. In the Podfile, I commented out the 3 pods, saved & closed.
2. I then ran `pod install` to delete the 3 pods.
3. I then ran `pod deintegrate`.
4. I then manually deleted `Podfile.lock` and `Workspace` from the project directory.
5. I re-opened the Podfile, uncommented out the 3 pods, and then explicitly specified the dependency versions that I used before the pod update that was causing the crash. See below:

   pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.8.0'

   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.27.0'

   pod 'Firebase/Crash', '4.8.0'

The project works as intended now. The App completes the IAP with no exceptions.

**Why is this occurring?** I am led to believe it's NOT a code issue, because this issue only occurs when I update my pods.

Comment: Did you ever find a permanent fix? My application is still having this problem...

Comment: I have not. Haven't touched the App in a few months, but it's on my radar to get the pods updated for it. In which case, I will need to resolve this issue permanently.

Comment: Ah ok. If you find a solution can you update this answer? I think the versions you have there are the only valid ones.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Additionally, if you figure it out before me, feel free to update the answer here!

Comment: @rassar - Just wondering if you have found any possible solutions to this issue. I'm working on it at the moment (it's STILL crashing...). So any information you can provide would be beneficial.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution I have right now is manually downloading the .framework files which is unsustainable. I don't really know what to do about it except to alert Google or the creators of Cocoapods.

Comment: @rassar I might be onto something.. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434076/firebaseinstanceid-is-not-installing-properly-with-cocoapods . I noticed that I am getting a far different amount of search results for timeIntervalSince1970 (within Xcode) before & after updating the pods. Most results lie within this FirebaseInstanceID directory that is not properly formatted after the pod update.