# FirebaseInstanceID is not installing properly with cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I performed a `pod update` to my project. This project uses the following pods:

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
 pod 'Fabric'
 pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Since the update, the Pods > FirebaseInstanceID directory is not properly formatted. It's just full of .h and .m files, and a Support Files directory.

Screenshot below:

[image: FirebaseInstanceID Not properly formatted]

Before I performed the `pod update`, the directory was properly formatted with Frameworks > FirebaseInstanceID.framework > Headers. *(FYI I deleted FirebaseCrash)*.

Screenshot below:

[image: FirebaseInstanceID Properly formatted]

This just happens in 1 particular project. I'm using Firebase in several other projects. None of them have this improper formatting of the FirebaseInstanceID directory when I update pods.

**Why is FirebaseInstanceID directory not properly formatted after a pod update?**

Comment: with Cocoapods you have to add to your podfile pod 'Firebase/Messaging', and then you will see "Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.3.4)" in your Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseInstanceID was recently open sourced and converted from a binary to a source CocoaPod. You'll notice in your installation that FirebaseCore has a similar structure of sources.

The Firebase SDKs are incrementally [open sourcing](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) over time. If you'd like to integrate binary frameworks into your app, you could try using [CocoaPods Rome](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Rome.md) or [Carthage](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md).

However, to be clear, using the default CocoaPods installation as you're doing is recommended and best supported.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. The real need for this question was hopefully trying to address a year-long problem I have been having here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325501/app-is-crashing-after-an-iap-only-after-podfiles-were-updated/51158324 . I thought that maybe the crashing issue was something to do with this new format for FirebaseInstanceID after a pod update. I'm marking this answer as correct, but I would *LOVE* your opinion on that old thread of mine that I linked! I'll be happy to clarify anything if needed.

Comment: I can take a look if you update or create a new question with Firebase 5.x and a more complete backtrace or reproducible example. If `pod update` isn't giving you recent versions, examine the `Podfile.lock` to find out why.